# How do I fix selenium, element not interactable?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I am trying to create a program that solves complex math problems that a user inputs. I am using the website mathpapa to solve these equations.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

PATH = 'C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe'

message = input("Enter a math problem: ")

web = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
web.get('https://www.mathpapa.com/algebra-calculator.html')


equation = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="source3"]/span[2]')
equation.send_keys(message + Keys.RETURN)

answer = WebDriverWait(web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="solout3"]/div[2]')))
print(answer.text)
```

I am running into an error on the line `equation = web.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="source3"]/span[2]')`
The error is saying the element is not interactable, is there any other way I can get it to input the message into textbar on mathpapa?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. You are trying to access equation input element before the page is fully loaded.
   This is why you are getting that error.
   You have to add a wait before that.
   I also changed the locator to be more precise.

```
equation = WebDriverWait(web, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#source3 textarea')))
equation.send_keys(message + Keys.RETURN)
```

2. Also you are using a wrong locator for the answer element.
   Try this:

```
answer = WebDriverWait(web, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#solout3 mn')))
print(answer.text)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is still returning the same error but in the send keys line saying it is not interactable. I believe for some reason it thinks we cannot input text there.

Comment: OK, please try the updated answer. I hope this time it will be better

Comment: That’s what I did, sorry I guess I should have specified that more but with your updated answer I still get that error

Comment: Are you sure? i have updated the selector to be `'#source3 textarea'`

Comment: Try setting `contentEditable` to true

Comment: Where would I set the contentEditable true, like where in the code?